# How do I install swtpm on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: virtualization

I added the virtual tpm2.0 to the machine but it keeps giving me this error? I'm using Ubuntu 21.10.

[image: 'unable to find 'swtpm' binary in $PATH:No such file or directory']

---

It's saying now

> Unable to find 'swtpm_setup' binary in $PATH no such file or directory

I did `sudo apt-get install swtpm_setup` in the terminal but just gives me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package swtpm_setup
```

I'm guessing I might need a PPA that has swtpm_setup; I'm not sure,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present time this package [is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/swtpm) from official repository only for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (development branch).

For previous 21.10 release you can use a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/swtpm) as shown below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/swtpm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install swtpm swtpm-tools
```

For 20.04 LTS, use different [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eitrue/+archive/ubuntu/swtpm) as shown below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:itrue/swtpm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install swtpm swtpm-tools
```

Comment: It's saying now Unable to find swtpm_setup binary in $PATH no such file or directory

Comment: Then use `sudo apt-get install swtpm-tools` and retry.

Comment: It said ;Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
swtpm-tools is already the newest version (0.7.0~dev1-~202107291110~1153~ubuntu21.10.1). I created a new win11 vm and it worked!

Comment: When I do `add-apt-repository` on 20.04, it says `ERROR: '~itrue' user or team does not exist.`